# JAVA drawing graphic

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw a rectangle on an image when the mouse button is pressed and released. And this part works just fine. Now I want to be able to see the rectangle while I drag the mouse, what I get is lots of rectangles being drawn please help.

```
class ActionTemp implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                letsdraw = tempimage.createGraphics();
                Point panelPoint = event.getPoint();
                sX = panelPoint.x;
                sY = panelPoint.y;
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                letsdraw.draw(new Rectangle2D.Float(Math.min(sX, curX),
                        Math.min(sY, curY), Math.abs(sX - curX),
                        Math.abs(sY - curY)));
                letsdraw.dispose();
                myPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        myPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point panelPoint = event.getPoint();
                curX = panelPoint.x;
                curY = panelPoint.y;
                letsdraw.draw(new Rectangle2D.Float(Math.min(sX, curX),
                        Math.min(sY, curY), Math.abs(sX - curX),
                        Math.abs(sY - curY)));
                myPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't paint directly to the image, instead maintain information about the area you want to paint and use the components paintComponent method to paint it over the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

The basic problem is, you painting directly to the image, which means, unless you have a separate copy, you're just compounding each successive rectangle on top of the last.

Instead, you want to paint each of them separately, something like...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SelectionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SelectionExample();
    }

    public SelectionExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle selection = new Rectangle();
        private Point clickPoint;

        private BufferedImage tempimage;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                tempimage = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/shane/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/thumnails/2.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    int minX = Math.min(e.getX(), clickPoint.x);
                    int minY = Math.min(e.getY(), clickPoint.y);
                    int maxX = Math.max(e.getX(), clickPoint.x);
                    int maxY = Math.max(e.getY(), clickPoint.y);

                    selection.x = minX;
                    selection.y = minY;
                    selection.width = maxX - minX;
                    selection.height = maxY - minY;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    clickPoint = new Point(e.getPoint());
                }

            };

            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return tempimage == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(tempimage.getWidth(), tempimage.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - tempimage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - tempimage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(tempimage, x, y, this);
            if (selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0) {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255, 64));
                g2d.fill(selection);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.draw(selection);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```